# Why does my code stop after i have used a for loop

Tags: python

This is the code i have so far for my gcse computing controlled assesment. I a trying to get the user to answer a question, then python will pick out specific words(that are the same as the words stored in a file) then link it to a solution.

```
global line
global userinput
global word
def main():
    global userinput
    name=input("What is your name")
        print("Hello " +name+ " and welcome to our troubleshooting system!")
    userinput=input("What is the problem with your mobile device?")
    userinput=userinput.split()
    if userinput=="":
        print("Please try again")
    power_problems()

def power_problems():
    global word
    global line
    global userinput
    with open("keywords_1","r+") as datafile_1:
    datafile_1.read()
        for line in datafile_1:
            if "userinput" in line:
                print("Hold the restart button for 30 seconds")
            else:
                phone_problems()

def phone_problems():
    global word
    global line
    global userinput
    with open("keywords_2", "r+") as datafile_2:
    datafile_2.read()
        for line in datafile_2:
            if "userinput" in line:
                print("Take the phone to the manufacturer to get a replacement")
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

My problem is that the code stops running after the for loop used in the function "power_problems" and i don't know why

Comment: What do you mean with "stops running"? Is there any error output?

Comment: Is the value of "userinput" actually in any of the lines in the file? Also, pass your variables to each function, don't use them globally unless you need to.

Comment: You call `main` which calls `power_problems`. `power_problems` returns, then `main` returns. Now you are at the every end of the script, so it exits.

Comment: Challenge yourself in the next Python program you write not to use the word `global` anywhere. You're currently using it as a crutch so you don't have to think about scope.

Comment: there is no errors output it just stops

Comment: And no userinput is not used in any of the lines of the file

Answer (score 0):

1. Check your indentation at `datafile_1.read()` and `datafile_1.read()`
2. `with open("keywords_1","r+") as datafile_1` - you typed the filename with no file type so the function will stop because there no such file or directory to read.
3. Try not to use `global` variables, it just **not safe**.

Comment: I thought the file type is the "r+"?

Comment: the file type is .txt, .dat, .docx.... and "r+" is the mode of the open function: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=open#open

Comment: i have changed the file to ("keywords_1.txt", r+) and the code still just stops and there is no error message it just stops and does not print anything